# how to express this kind of non greedy regular expression in python?

Tags: python, regex

```
s1='haha "h1" "hi"'
s2='haha "h1" "hi hi"'
```

I want to get  "hi" from s1 ,and "hi hi" from s2.

```
>>> re.search('".*"$',s1).group()
'"h1" "hi"'
>>> re.search('".*"$',s2).group()
'"h1" "hi hi"'
>>> re.search('"*?.*"$',s1).group()
'haha "h1" "hi"'
>>> re.search('"*?.*"$',s2).group()
'haha "h1" "hi hi"'
```

Comment: Which `hi` you are talking about? There is a minimum of two `hi`s in both the strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just capture everything that is not `"` between `"`:

```
>>> re.search('"[^"]*"$',s1).group()
'"hi"'
>>> re.search('"[^"]*"$',s2).group()
'"hi hi"'
```

Comment: if s1='haha "h1" ""hi"' ,how can i get ""hi"  from it?

Comment: You could adjust to `re.search('"+[^"]*"+$',s1)`: between 1 or more `"` from both side.

Answer (score 4):

```
".*?"$
```

Try this:

https://regex101.com/r/fA6wE2/22

You can use `re.findall(r'".*?"$',test_str)`

The problem with your regex `re.search('".*"$',s1).group()` was that `.*` is greedy and it will grab up until the last `"` from first `"`. So make it non-greedy by putting `?` ahead of it. Make it a lazy matching.